# I've created multiple DMG files from the same folder - checksum is different on each?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, dmg, apfs

Quite some time ago I've noticed that even if I create DMG files from the same directory, with same files and etc, the results are always different. Not only their size is ~15 bytes shorter/longer from one another, but their SHA checksums (and their contents, when being viewed from the HEX editor) differ drastically. Just out of curiosity, I've created 5 compressed unencrypted DMG files from the same folder containing nothing but a single text file. The results are:

- 0.dmg | size - 26 204 bytes, checksum - 5ba9ba0ee4d8ec5ba4718f1b491baf31c2c4e642
- 1.dmg | size - 26 221 bytes, checksum - a86d76f6c07ee5a81c0aefb31b6fd40ef787ebd5
- 2.dmg | size - 26 235 bytes, checksum - a31f4cf29e4e2858b7ac63c82574499200d81108
- 3.dmg | size - 26 209 bytes, checksum - f3c19414279b6d6b94b90341453906e4a69e28dd
- 4.dmg | size - 26 217 bytes, checksum - 9603c0334125762fc7908343e3ee400e038fe779

I've been browsing the internet hoping to find anything about the "data randomizer in APFS", but... obviously couldn't find a single thing, and in addition, not a lot of people actually knew about this "feature". Is there any info about it?

I'm running macOS 10.12.6, the DMG files were created using Disk Utility, but I get the same results with hdiutil.

Comment: We need more information to provide an adequate answer. However, I suspect that the source is actually changing, even if only in metadata (access timestamps, etc.), and that the DMG reflects these changes. Have you tried testing with different file systems in the container?

Comment: If the bytes changed, the data changed, which means the checksum will change. I suspect jsejcksn is right and metadata is being changed (15 bytes is very small). Try zipping the data first, then creating dmg of that and see if the data and checksums stay the same, or protecting the directory before creating the dmg.

Comment: I've set the file system to RW and created 2 DMG files, and one of them is 40 bytes larger than the second one. Perhaps you're right, and the metadata of that text file changes ("last opened", maybe?) I'll try writing a simple script that will output the file's info, and hopefully some useful result will show up.

Comment: I'll also lock the file, as Christian suggested.

Comment: Alright, so it's the access time that was changing constantly. I've fixed it by disabling the "atime" in launch daemons, but the new problem appeared: despite the fact that the metadatas are pretty much the same (stats are identical now), DMG files are still different. What can this be...

Comment: @L0W_P1X3L: You'd have to examine the detailed structure of the disk image to find what changed. This'll be much easier if it's uncompressed. But in general, you shouldn't expect the same files to generate the exact same disk image -- the disk image format can include (or depend on) lots of extraneous info that's probably really hard to control. I'm not sure why you want to get the same disk image multiple times, but whatever your actual goal is, you should find a different way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copies of an existing `dmg` will be identical but separately created `dmg` files will not.

## Effectively Guaranteed to Differ

The [Apple Disk Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image) `.dmg` format effectively guarantees that no two disk images will be bit for bit identical. Equality between disk images containing the same contents is not a practical requirement of the format.

### UUID within the `0x6B6F6C79` / `koly` Block

Within the `dmg` file format is the [`koly` structure](http://newosxbook.com/DMG.html). This structure includes a **SegmentID** of type [`uuid_t`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/uuid_t). This is a 128 bit Universally Unique Identifier ([UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)). The SegmentID identifier alone will ensure that every `dmg` file differs by more than one bit.

Using [HFSleuth](http://newosxbook.com/tools/hfsleuth.html) on the iTunes 11.0 disk image shows the embedded UUID:

```
HFSleuth> ver
Verbose output is on
HFSleuth> fs iTunes11.dmg
KOLY header found at 200363895:
    UDIF version 4, Header Size: 512
    Flags:1
    Rsrc fork: None
    Data fork: from 0, spanning 200307220 bytes
    XML plist: from 200307220, spanning 56675 bytes (to 200363895)
    Segment #: 1, Count: 1
    Segment UUID: 626f726e-7743259b-6086eb93-4b42fb65
    Running Data fork offset 0
    Sectors: 1022244
```

In the example above, the line `Segment UUID: 626f726e-7743259b-6086eb93-4b42fb65` is a universally unique identifier embedded in the disk image.

### One Bit Differences and Hash Functions

A difference in one bit should result in a 50% or more change in a cryptographic hash function output, such as SHA-2.

The use of a UUID within the structure is not to ensure every disk image is unique but to ease segment identification within the disk image. That a UUID provides uniqueness properties beyond the scope of the disk image is a by-product of the UUID's use.